# Почему функция не работает?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Проблема в том, что в функции в setTimeout, `array_one[a] == undefined`

```
function timeStart() {
    var array_one = new Array("#bmw1", "#bmw2", "#bmw3", "#bmw4", "#bmw5");
    var array_two = new Array("#mercedes1", "#mercedes2", "#mercedes3", "#mercedes4", "#mercedes5")

    for (var a = 0, b = 1000; a < 5; ++a, b += 2000) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(array_one[a] + "," + array_two[a]).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                $(array_one[a + 1] + "," + array_two[a + 1]).fadeIn(3000)
            })
        }
        , b)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Упростим вопрос до такого:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var z = new Array("1", "2", "3");

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert(z[i]);
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Почему он не работает (alert показывает undefined)? Потому что в момент вызова i = 3, цикл уже завершился, и значение массива берется за его границами.

**Добавление**.

Как сделать правильно? Надо передать аргумент в функцию.

```
var z = new Array("1", "2", "3");

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(function (i) {
        alert(z[i]);
    }(i), 1000);
}
```

Comment: да я это уже понял, как мне написать норм, что я хочу

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/81348/

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: зачем плодить одну и туже ветку на форуме?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky - кто-нибудь это запускал?

Answer (score 0):

переназначьте в цикле переменную **b** и уже новую переменную используйте как параметр для временного интервала.

```
function timeStart() {
    var array_one = new Array("#bmw1", "#bmw2", "#bmw3", "#bmw4", "#bmw5");
    var array_two = new Array("#mercedes1", "#mercedes2", "#mercedes3", "#mercedes4", "#mercedes5")

    for (var a = 0, b = 1000; a < 5; ++a, b += 2000) {
        set t=b;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(array_one[a] + "," + array_two[a]).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                $(array_one[a + 1] + "," + array_two[a + 1]).fadeIn(3000)
            })
        }
        , t)
    }
}
```

Возможно так же следует переназначить и переменную **a**. Такой уж жуткий этот *setTimeout*.

```
function timeStart() {
    var array_one = new Array("#bmw1", "#bmw2", "#bmw3", "#bmw4", "#bmw5");
    var array_two = new Array("#mercedes1", "#mercedes2", "#mercedes3", "#mercedes4", "#mercedes5")

    for (var a = 0, b = 1000; a < 5; ++a, b += 2000) {
        set t=b;
        set mas=a;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(array_one[mas] + "," + array_two[mas]).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                $(array_one[mas + 1] + "," + array_two[mas + 1]).fadeIn(3000)
            })
        }
        , t)
    }
}
```

Comment: не помогает, там еще ощибка из-за seTimeOut в цикле + анимация с временем задается