# Помогите сделать задумку

Tags: jquery, javascript

В общем я хочу, чтобы картинки медленно одна за другой исчезали и всплывали, но вот проблема из-за того, что в цикле TimeOut. Помогите сделать рабочим этот код?

```
function timeStart() {
    var array_one = new Array("#bmw1", "#bmw2", "#bmw3", "#bmw4", "#bmw5");
    var array_two = new Array("#mercedes1", "#mercedes2", "#mercedes3", "#mercedes4", "#mercedes5")

    for (var a = 0, z = 1, b = 1000; a < 5; ++a, b += 2000, ++z) {
        setTimeout(zes(a, z), 1000)
    }

    function zes(one_value, two_value) {
        $(array_one[one_value] + "," + array_two[one_value]).fadeOut(1000)
        $(array_one[two_value] + "," + array_two[two_value]).fadeIn(1000)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо сделать также, как написано в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/81330#81345), то есть передать фактические значения параметров цикла в функцию:

```
setTimeout(function f(x, y) {} (x, y), 1000);
```